# How to set the path of a CSV file that is in account storage in azure data factory pipeline

Tags: ssis, azure-storage, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have created a SSIS package that reads from a CSV file (using the `Flat file connection manager`) and loads records into a database. I have deployed it on Azure data factory pipeline and I need to give the path of the CSV file as a parameter. I have created a azure storage account and uploaded the source file there as shown below.

Can I just give the URL of the source file for the Import file in the SSIS package settings as shown below? I tried it but it is currently throwing 2906 error. I am new to Azure - appreciate any help here.

[image: Azure account storage - Source file:]

[image: Azure DF - Execute SSIS Package]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you said Excel and then you said CSV. Those are two different formats. But since you mention the flat file connection manager, I'm going to assume you meant CSV. If not, let me know and I'll update my answer.

I think you will need to install the [SSIS Feature Pack for Azure](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54798) and use the [Azure Storage Connection Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/azure-storage-connection-manager?view=sql-server-2017). You can then use the [Azure Blob Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/azure-blob-source?view=sql-server-2017) in your data flow task (it supports CSV files). When you add the blob source, the GUI should help you create the new connection manager. There is a [tutorial on MS SQL Tips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4447/how-to-import-data-from-azure-blob-storage-to-a-local-file-with-sql-server-integration-services/) that shows each step. It's a couple years old, but I don't think much has changed.

As a side thought, is there a reason you chose to use SSIS over native ADF V2? It does a nice job of [copying data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) from blob storage to a database.

Comment: My bad. It's a CSV file not excel. Edited the question.

Comment: I want to do some fuzzy lookups and this is the reason I went with SSIS. Not sure if the same can be done with ADF.